# System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator does not exist

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to derive a class from System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator. However if I add a reference to System.IdentityModel.Selectors I still can't add System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator as it tells me it does not exist in the namespace. Microsofts own documentation says it is in there and there are many examples on the web using this class, however it just refuses to recognise it on my machine......

Comment: Without example code, without error messages, without any details, it's hard to help

Comment: I have already answered my own question below.... Also the code and the error are in the question above......

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have found the issue. I needed to also add a reference to System.IdentityModel.

Answer (score 6):

You have to add the reference of [System.IdentityModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145031%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> The System.IdentityModel namespaces contain types that are used to
>   provide authentication and authorization for .NET applications.